# Linker error / Best way to make a "helper" class in C++ which can be included in multiple files

Tags: c++, linker

I need a helper class with functions which are useful everywhere in my program. Ideally, I wanted a file with a single namespace like below which I can include anywhere in my program:

```
namespace myhelpers{
  int func(){
    //function with implementation in one file. 
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because I can't have multiple definitions of the function, so I separated into .h and .cpp and still get errors. Code below:

myhelpers.h

```
#ifndef MYHELPERS
#define MYHELPERS
#include <vector>

class myhelpers {
public:
    template <class M>
    static std::vector<M> func1(double i);
};
#endif
```

myhelpers.cpp

```
#include "myhelpers.h"
template<class M> // <--making this function a non-template function fixes the error. 
std::vector<M> myhelpers::func1(double i ) {
    return std::vector<double>(5);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "someclass.h"
int main() {
    // also want to use my helpers here. 
}
```

someclass.cpp

```
#include "myhelpers.h"
#include "someclass.h"
int someclass::func(int i) {
    myhelpers::func1<double>(10.0);
    return 1;
}
```

someclass.h

```
class someclass {
    int func(int i);
};
```

I get this linker error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<double,class std::allocator > __cdecl myhelpers::func1(double)" (??$func1@N@myhelpers@@SA?AV?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function "private: int __thiscall someclass::func(int)" (?func@someclass@@AAEHH@Z)  directory/someclass.obj 1

If I remove the template from the myhelpers function this linker error disappears, I don't see how this template function changes fixes the error, but I need the templates in my helper functions.
I've spent hours looking online for the best way to have a helper class like this but can't find a good answer.

**Thanks.**

Comment: You can always make a namespace-scope function `inline` or `static`.

Comment: ***Severity Code Description*** Note: the output tab has the error message in a better format than the errors list. Sometimes the message will also be more verbose as the errors list shortens the message at times.

Comment: Ok, so if I make a namespace filled with inline functions, I should be able to include it anywhere in my project ?

Comment: It will work however I would question if you want to make them all inline versus implementing the larger functions in a translation unit.